# Apply method immediately after returning to page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two pages: page A has a "search" function, page B has a "select language" function. I navigate from page A to page B to select my language. Then I want to pop back from page B to page A with the new chosen language and perform the search automatically for that language.

I pass my chosen language from Page B to A by using SharedPrefs (which is working fine). So all I need is when I return to Page A, for the search function to get automatically triggered.

Is that possible in Flutter?

I tried using `initState` but that only works once when the widget is first built. I also tried `didUpdateWidget` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this when navigating to `PageB` from `PageA`

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(_) => PageB())).then((value) {
  // you have come back to the pageA, now perform your logic 
  callThisMethod();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working, however my search results stay the same in the ListView. Is there something else I need to do? DidupdateWidget?

Comment: Try calling `setState((){})` inside above block